# Why am I getting a Redirect Loop for the following RewriteRules?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm getting a Rewrite Loop error for the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(apps|site).* [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://site.mysite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Why is this happening, what am I missing?

I've tested the following URLs, and they seem to redirect ok:

```
www.mysite.com/
www.mysite.com/apps
www.mysite.com/apps
mysite.com/
mysite.com/apps
mysite.com/apps/about
mysite.com/site
```

BUT

```
www.mysite.com/site
```

does not want to redirect, the rest all redirects to http://site.mysite.com as expected?

Comment: You are missing `%{REQUEST_URI}` after the last `RewriteCond`. Like this: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(apps|site).* [NC]`

Comment: Cool, added it in, but still no can do, /apps redirects, but not /site?

Comment: If it works for `mysite.com` the problem is not with last rule-set as it doesn't depend on any specific domain. It is somewhere else. Does `http://www.mysite.com/site` exist? If so, that's the reason. If not, try removing temporarily the top rule-set to add `www` (2 lines) and test again. If it works, those 2 lines are the problem.

Comment: I'm starting to suspect that it's being handled by a virtual host setup elsewhere I don't know of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out we had a site folder in our public, which somehow got the action before the .htaccess. Not sure why this happened, but upon removing this redundant folder, everything is working 100%